# PHP array_slice() почему порядок указывается на 1 больше?

Tags: php

Почему в `php array_slice()` порядок указывается на 1 больше? Допустим мне надо выбрать первые 4 элемента массива, я делаю это так - `@array_slice($data, 0, 4)` но ведь по логике `0 - первый, 1 - второй, 2 - третий, 3 - четвертый`. То есть "срез" `0-3` (включительно). Но корректно работает именно `0, 4`.

Comment: 1-ый аргумент это начальный элемент - 0 (т.е. 1-ый элемент в массиве), 2-ой аргумент количество элементов с текущей позиции - 4, что не понятно то? )

Comment: Но Вы же указываете количество, а не конечный индекс.